# Eclipse shows "Workspace in use or cannot be created, choose different one"

Tags: eclipse

If I log out & login again I am able to launch eclipse without the previously mentioned error. I am using Ubuntu 12.04(64 bit).

Comment: Where is your workspace located? Thanks.

Comment: Located on an unmounted disk. Should it be mounted permenantly all the time

Answer (score 2):

This message is because there is a previous Eclipse process hanging around interrupting the one you are trying to launch.

```
ps aux | grep eclipse
```

find the eclipse process that's still running. I killed both the `/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse` and `/usr/bin/java` processes. The process number is the number immediately adjacent to your user name. Then run

```
kill -9 [process number]
```

(without the brackets). That oughta do it!

Comment: I would suggest to try a regular `kill` first (without the `-9` option). A `-9` will send a fairly destructive signal whereas a regular `SIGTERM` will shut it down gracefully (less likely to loose data).

Comment: @gertvdijk good point